# Remove leading zeros while adding up values in two textboxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have three textboxes, the values given in the first and second textbox will be summed and showed automatically, in the third textbox. My textboxes does not accept decimal values, i.e it accepts only whole numbers.

The problem is, if I have leading zeros in the first two text boxes, it produces weird results in the third textbox.

```js
    function getValues(val)
    {
    var carryVol=parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=txtCarryOver.ClientID%>').value)||0;
    var FreshVol=parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=txtFreshVol.ClientID%>').value)||0;
    var target=carryVol+FreshVol;
    document.getElementById('<%=txtTotalVol.ClientID%>').value=target;   
       }
```

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCarryOver" runat="server" Enabled="true" TabIndex="3" Width="150px"
                                        onkeyup="getValues(1)" onKeyDown="return validateQty(event)" MaxLength="3"                                             Height="13px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtFreshVol" runat="server" Enabled="true" TabIndex="3" Width="150px"
                                        onkeyup="getValues(2)" onKeyDown="return validateQty(event)" MaxLength="3" Height="13px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalVol" runat="server" Enabled="true" TabIndex="3" Width="150px"
                                        onKeyDown="preventBackspace();" Height="13px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Also, I have already used onkeydown and onkeyup, help me to call the js function too, I always quite confused how to call a js function.

Comment: A Google search for "onkeyup asp textbox" gives plenty of results.  What have you tried besides this code?

Comment: It may possible that parseInt function giving you 'NaN' and when you add it with number it will produce  weird  result. so first you need to check what parseint function is returing to you.

Comment: pls help me out... 001+025 gives me 22.. it should return 26 right?

Comment: @sean I don't hav an idea about doing it..i tired it in ontextchanged, but it didn;'t workout as the addition must happen automatically, before it is saved

Comment: It could be that your 0-prefixed numbers are being interpreted as Octal (base 8), while the result is printed in Decimal (base 10). 001 (base 8) is 1 (base 10). 025 (base 8) is 21 (base 10). The sum is 22 (base 10). You should be able to verify this by trying various combinations (with and without leading zeroes).

Comment: ya I get u...does this have any solution @dave

Comment: Use regex with events

Comment: ok @novice.....

Comment: @dave thanks for your explanation it helped to get what I wanted.. :)